# ¿Cómo ejecutar correctamente una función desde un objeto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, clase, python-3.7

tengo la siguiente función junto con una clase. La función es lo primero que está definido, luego la clase y el la ventana de tkinter. El problema es que ejecuta la tab de tkinter notebook pero al darle al botón no crea los labels que debería. He intentado cambiar dónde se hace el pack() del labelframe pero sigue sin funcionar. No sé si debería meter la función dentro de la clase o qué debería hacer. Muchas gracias. Edit:También he intentado usar `tabName=tabControl.select()` y `textWidget = tabControl.nametowidget(tabName)` para que el labelframe se crease en textWidget, pero tampoco funciona

````
def msearch():
        global label
        try:
            label.master.destroy()
        except:
            pass
        busqueda=entryname_valor.get()
        lista=os.listdir("C:\u005cUsers\u005cD\u005cBase de datos")
        res = [i for i in lista if busqueda in i]
        import glob
        listatexto=glob.glob("C:\u005cUsers\u005cD\u005cBase de datos\u005c*\u005c*.txt")
    #print(listatexto,type(listatexto))
        lista_match=[]
        tabnombre=tabControl.select()
        textWidget = tabControl.nametowidget(tabnombre)
        group =tk.LabelFrame(textWidget, text="Resultados", padx=10, pady=10)
        group.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        for i in listatexto:
            with open(i) as f:
                 if busqueda in f.read():
                     lista_match.append(i)
        res_clean=[]
        for i in res:
             i='C:\\Users\\D\\Base de datos\\'+i+'\\'+i+".txt"
             res_clean.append(i)
        definitiva=res_clean+lista_match
        definitiva=set(definitiva)
        print(definitiva)
        resultados_lista=[]
        for i in definitiva:
            filename=os.path.basename('\\'+i)
            somestring='this is some string rec'
            somestring = re.sub('.txt$', '', filename)
            resultados_lista.append(somestring)
        print(resultados_lista)
        for i,url in enumerate(resultados_lista):
            v=tk.StringVar()
            tabName=tabControl.select()
            textWidget = tabControl.nametowidget(tabName)
            print(textWidget)
            label=tk.Label(group,textvariable=v, cursor="hand2")
            v.set(url)
            f = font.Font(label, label.cget("font"))
            f.configure(underline=True)
            label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
            label.after(60000, label.pack_forget)
            label.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e,url=url:abrir_resultado(url))`
`class SearchTab(ttk.Frame, CustomNotebook):
    def __init__(self,main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        global entryname_valor
        entryname_valor=tk.StringVar()
        titulo =tk.Label(self, text="Introduce tu búsqueda")
        titulo.config(font=("Courier", 25))
        titulo.pack()
        mEntryname = tk.Entry(main_window, width=50, font=("Courier", 20), textvariable=entryname_valor).place(width=750,height=50,x=0, y=100)
        mSearch = tk.Button(main_window,text='Search',bg='white', command = msearch, height=5, width=15, font=fuente).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        fuente2 = font.Font(family='Herculanum', size=12, weight='bold')

top = tk.Tk()
top.title("Programa de busqueda")
top.geometry("750x500")
fuente = font.Font(family='Herculanum', size=17, weight='bold')
tabControl = CustomNotebook(top)     
tab_search = SearchTab(tabControl)            
tabControl.add(tab_search, text='Búsqueda')
tabControl.pack(side=tk.TOP)
top.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Aunque no necesariamente tiene por qué ser un método de una clase, sí necesitará tener acceso a las variables adecuadas, por lo que, o haces esas variables globales (no muy recomendable), o las haces atributos de objeto, y así puede compartirlas vía `self`. Por ejemplo, la variable `entry_name` que usas en esa función ¿de dónde sale?

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a cuando uso ```busqueda=entryname_valor.get()```. En la clase SearchTab es donde está definida```global entryname_valor entryname_valor=tk.StringVar()``` Como dices que no es muy recomendable hacer esa variable global, puedo intentar hacerlo via self. Pero de todas maneras, el programa se ejecuta correctamente, solo falla la parte del label (y si el valor de entryname.get() es nulo, aparece el labelframe, pero no los labels).

Comment: ¿puedes poner el código completo en algún pastebin/gist para que pueda yo probar a ejecutarlo a ver si veo qué pasa?

Comment: Claro, aquí lo tienes https://pastebin.com/LQJ0jN0U lo único que para que funcione bien tienes que crear la carpeta C:\Users\D\Base de datos financiera e instalar los módulos que usa, (para hacer conceptos de ejemplo usa la pestaña añadir nuevo dentro de la propia aplicación)

Comment: He conseguido resolverlo usando place en vez de pack con el labelframe. El problema que hay ahora @abulafia es que al crear inicialmente una instancia de SearchtTab funciona bien, pero en el menú Abrir>Búsqueda (que lleva asociada una función que hace exactamente lo mismo, iniciar una instancia de SearchTab) se solapan los botones y la segunda pestaña de búsqueda no funciona https://imgur.com/SHYnZP5

Comment: Edit del comentario anterior: sí funciona, lo que pasa es que crea los elementos de SearchTab en todas pestañas. ¿Será que main_window no es lo que debería usar en esa clase? O a lo mejor es algún problema con super()

Answer (score 0):

Una solución provisional que he encontrado sería usar self en la clase en vez de main_window, declarar una variable que sea igual que self y hacerla global, y crear el labelframe usando esa variable como argumento. Es provisional porque da errores al tener varias pestañas activas

```
class SearchTab(ttk.Frame, CustomNotebook):
    def __init__(self,main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        global entryname_valor
        global tab
        tab=self
        entryname_valor=tk.StringVar()
        titulo =tk.Label(self, text="Introduce tu búsqueda")
        titulo.config(font=("Courier", 25))
        titulo.pack()
        mEntryname = tk.Entry(self, width=50, font=("Courier", 20), textvariable=entryname_valor).place(width=750,height=50,x=0, y=100)
        mSearch = tk.Button(self,text='Search',bg='white', command = msearch, height=5, width=15, font=fuente).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        fuente2 = font.Font(family='Herculanum', size=12, weight='bold')
```